# Stored Procedure Does and Does Not Exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an SQL Server 2008 R2 database with a stored procedure that may or may not exist.

If I run `sp_help spThing`, it returns a row as if it existed (Name: spThing, Owner: dbo, Type: stored procedure).

If I try to create a new stored procedure with the same name, I get the error "There is already an object named 'spThing' in the database".

BUT

If I run `SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.spThing')`, it returns NULL.

If I run `EXEC spThing`, it says "Could not find stored procedure 'spThing'".

If I run `DROP spThing`, it says "Cannot drop the procedure 'spThing', because it does not exist or you do not have permission".

If I run `SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'spThing'`, I get no row.

If I run `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'spThing'`, I get no row.

All these were run from the same connection, as an administrative user.

Does the stored procedure exist?

Edit:

The SP itself is a trivial select, along the lines of:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spThing
    @Param int
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT strThing
    FROM tblThing
    WHERE lngParam = @Param;

END
```

Comment: Please provide `DDL` of your sp.

Comment: It's just a trivial select query, added to the question.

Comment: Is very strange, if object exists `OBJECT_ID('<schema>.<object_name>')` always is not null. Check you default schema name.

Comment: I know :-S

I'm wondering whether there are multiple places in which SQL Server stores objects internally, and for some reason mine is in one but not another.

Comment: Are you on a case sensitive collation? If so are you using the same casing for `spThing` consistently in all of these attempts?

Comment: No, it's a case insensitive collation.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the SQL Server instance?

Comment: Nenad: Yes, that did the trick. No idea what went wrong...it must have got itself in a funny state somehow. Feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

All works fine -

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.spThing') IS NOT NULL
     DROP PROCEDURE dbo.spThing
GO

SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.spThing')
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spThing

    @Param INT

AS BEGIN

    SELECT strThing
    FROM dbo.tblThing
    WHERE lngParam = @Param

END
GO

SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.spThing')
```

Output -

```
-----------
NULL
(1 row(s) affected)

-----------
664283184
(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't get to try this before restarting the SQL Server instance, so I'm not sure whether this would have worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[spThing]')
           AND TYPE IN (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[spThing];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spThing]
AS
BEGIN 

-- Code here

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

For my answer, it exists in dbo.spThing but not exist in sys.spThing

i do not have specific answer:

there is 2 type of store procedure , 1 is for system, and i is for databaseobject. The 1 paul and devart try is to create a dbo.spthing.

firstly, paul say if `SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'spThing'` return no row mean not exists in system stored procedure and devart try is create in dbo.Spthing and will return result.

just wondering ,your question is correct on this line or not SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.spThing')
because it will exist instead of not exist

further more , you did run `sp_help spThing` and owner is dbo so your dbo.spthing is exist. but not sys.spthing

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `SELECT OBJECT_ID('sys.spThing')` returned NULL too. It's fixed now though.